# Google script : cannot access e.user on edit change

Tags: google-apps-script

The following is my algorithm:

- Make a form
- In the script editor, create a script with this function:

  ```
  function displayUser(e){
    Logger.log(e.user);
    Logger.log(e.user.getEmail());
  }
  ```
- Create a trigger which runs `displayUser` after event `From spreadsheet` `On edit`.
- Edit the spreadsheet of the form

The logging output will displays:

> *undefined*

The execution transcript says:

> *Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot call method "getEmail" of undefined. (line 3, file "Code")*

However, the google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events) specifies that `e.user`:

> Always returns a User object, representing the owner of the Spreadsheet

It's not the case here as `e.user` is undefined.

I used this command before the new access right management system of Google, and it worked fine - it returned the information about the owner of the spreadsheet.

Did I make any mistake?

Comment: The script shown above works as expected. What other information can you give us to see how we can help?

Comment: @user2661246 - you're right, it doesn't return the owner of the ss. when renamed as onEdit() and working as a simple trigger it does return the effective user of the sheet but I guess that's not what you need ;-) - I personally never used that before so I cannot confirm it worked before but if you're sure you could check the issue tracker (I did and didn't find any mention of it) and eventually create a new one.

Comment: @William : what did you mean by "works as expected" ?

Comment: Indeed, with the new authentication system has changed the behavior of triggers, before the change, any function defined for the trigger onEdit was receiving the following: user, source, range, value. Now only to define the function as onEdit receive the following: user, source, range, value, the rest receive only: source, range, value. It would have to validate it's not a bug.

Comment: @Serge: My tests were done with the previous authentication system, so I worked properly.

Comment: @user2661246: Renaming **displayUser** by **onEdit** function should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you're right, it doesn't return the owner of the ss. when renamed as onEdit() and working as a simple trigger it does return the effective user of the sheet but I guess that's not what you need ;-) - I personally never used that before so I cannot confirm it worked before but if you're sure you could check the issue tracker (I did and didn't find any mention of it) and eventually create a new one.